# Issue in convert project from vc6 to vc9

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-c++-6, visual-c++-2008

I have a project that was build in vc6,Now I have to convert it into vc9.

In the code there is line

```
CMapStringToOb  cLogPathMap;
ofstream        tlogFile;
```

But when I build the project the following error occur.

**error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'tlogFile'**

**error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int**

When I go to definition of **ofstream** the file **iosfwd** is opened where ofstream defined as

```
typedef basic_ofstream<char, char_traits<char> > ofstream;
```

Comment: So you changed the #include from iostream.h to iostream?  Then also fix the namespace, it is std::ofstream

Answer (score 0):

The following microsoft suggests to include fstream:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9cabcax%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

So put the following line in your header includes for that c++ file:

```
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: @vikky: Please notice, that in VC6, the filename was `fstream.h`.  Now it needs to be just `fstream`, according to the C++ Standard (which wasn't ready yet when VC6 was made).

Comment: How about adding using namespace std; after your includes.

Comment: The error message is basically saying ofstream is not defined.

Comment: I am not sure what you edited. Did you add using namespace std; like in the following example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/tellp/ or change the second line to read std::ofstream        tlogFile;